# how to remove sonata project link from sonata admin pannel

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-2.8

how can I remove sonata project link from sonata admin panel.

[image]

Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: do you have access to CSS files and can edit on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need tyo override `sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig`

it is at line 247:

```
{% block side_bar_after_nav %}
   <p class="text-center small" style="border-top: 1px solid #444444; padding-top: 10px">
     {% block side_bar_after_nav_content %}
        <a href="https://sonata-project.org" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">sonata project</a>
     {% endblock %}
   </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The following code done the trick.
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}
{% block side_bar_after_nav %}


{% endblock %}

Answer (score 0):

Redefine sonata template:

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        layout: 'admin/app_layout.html.twig'
```

And in template redefine block `side_bar_after_nav_content`:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block side_bar_after_nav_content %}
    {# Removes original sonata link #}
{% endblock %}
```